# Minimum paragraph lineskip when flushing bottom

Tags: vertical-alignment, parskip

For my thesis, I have `\documentclass[twoside]{book}` along with `\flushbottom` to fill the page all the way to the bottom. However, on a number of pages the spacing between paragraphs is too small to my taste. I've tried using `\setlength{\parskip}{1em}` to force the paragraph spacing, but that obviously breaks `\flushbottom`. Is there a way to set a minimum parskip, while still allowing `\flushbottom` to stretch that value if needed?

Comment: `\setlength{\parskip}{1em plus 1em}` ?

Comment: Nifty, I didn't know about that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining `\parskip` with some expandable glue (but not contractable) will allow `\flushbottom` to be satisfied, but prevent the parskip from shrinking too small.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\flushbottom
\parskip4pt plus3pt
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-22]
\end{document}
```

[image]